# How to format text in telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I can't figure out how to format the text in the Telegram bot.

The code is the following:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def help(message: telebot.types.Message):
    text = "<b> Test message </b>"
    bot.reply_to(message, text)
```

Where should I put `parse_mode='HTML'`?

I tried:

1.`bot.reply_to(message, text, parse_mode='HTML')`

2.`bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')`

I want the bot to format the message: make individual words or sentences bold, italic or underlined.

Answer (score 1):

The default `parse_mode` can be passed to the `TeleBot` class like so:

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode='MARKDOWN')
```

If you want to set it for a single message, `send_message` also excepts `parse_mode`:

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>some text</b>', parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formatting` package from Telebot to format your text like this:

```
from telebot import formatting

formatting.hbold("hello")
formatting.hitalic("world")
formatting.hunderline("!")
```

See the [pytba docs](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formatting.html) for all formatting styles.